# Computer science. Need explanation about asynchronous IO automaton

Tags: concurrency, computer-science, distributed-computing, automaton

I'm currently reading Nancy Lynch book about distributed systems, chapter about IO automaton. And I have following questions related to book exercise 8.13(c).

We are given some automaton A with sig(A) is empty. Traces(P) is the set of sequences over {1,2} in which every occurrence of 1 is immediately followed by a 2. I need to show that P is neither a safety property nor a liveness property. and show explicitly that P could be expressed as intersections of S and L.

Here is my problem: I can show that P is not safety because it breaks prefix-closed property, e.g. {2,1,2} has no prefix belonging to P (it should be of the  form {...,1} which is impossible for P). But I don't know how to deal with L property -- either it is empty or include trace(P) -- trace(P) $\subset$ trace(L). If it is empty then traces(P) is empty because traces(P)= traces(S) $\cap$ traces(L) which is wrong. So I think that traces(P) is subset of traces(L).

Is my conclusion related to traces(L) is right?

How can I explicitly express traces(P)=traces(S) $\cap$ traces(L) for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you are going to get an answer without a lot more information. You are using gooblygook academic notation that has no standard meaning.

Comment: @user3344003: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83907/question-about-io-automaton

Comment: Solved here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83907/question-about-io-automaton/87321#87321